# how to enable xmpp chat in empathy

Tags: empathy, pidgin, nimbuzz

since nimbuzz have no linux version I am using pidgin to chat with nimbuzz friends .

pidgin can handle nimbuzz via xmpp protocol
but now I  want to do it via empathy .How to do it ,

Edit: 
I tried jabber entry in the empathy ,But it shows certificate error
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

When you have Empathy open, press <kbd>F4</kbd> to open the account manager. Click the + button in the lower left corner. Select "Jabber" as account type. Jabber and XMPP is the same thing. XMPP is just a new name.